# user input and text choice as well in django model

Tags: python, django

In django model, user input and text choices to be filled to a field name.

```
class Store(models.Model):
   class Size(model.TextChoices):
        MEDIUM = "M", "Medium"
        LARGE = "L","Large"
   shirt_size = models.CharField("Shirt Size", choices=Size.choices, default=Size.MEDIUM)
```

When django is run with admin to add records to table, it will show drop down to choose Size which are available and at the same time, i want to have custom fill as well for user input(S, XXL, etc..)

Comment: You might try storing Size as a separate model and having a ForeignKey to that model on your Store model. In the admin this will be displayed as a dropdown with a plus symbol next to it that can be used to add new Size entries

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I usually do that:

```py
class Store(models.Model):
    MEDIUM = 'M'
    LARGE = 'L'
    SIZE_CHOICES = (
        (MEDIUM, 'Medium'),
        (LARGE, 'Large')
    )
    shirt_size = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text="Shirt Size", choices=SIZE_CHOICES, default=MEDIUM)
```

Also don't forget the [max_length](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField.max_length) required argument in your CharField. I have set it to 20 for possible expansion of `SIZE_CHOICES`, but only for `M` and `L` setting it to 1 would be enough.

Comment: Thank you for proposal. However, here i want to have a flexibility to the user, it should be able to accept user input as well in the charField ie both choices and user input as well.

Comment: I guess you should add another field for user input (would suggest TextField).